# How to use group function in Pandas Pivot table

Tags: pandas, pivot, grouping

I have a time field in hh:mm:ss.ms format. I am making a pivot table using this time field as index. I want to perform grouping with suppose start range 12:30 to 13:30, 13:30:14:30 and so on.

Example:

ActualTime
12:30
12:31
12:46
13:05
13:22
13:48
14:05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) with `timedelta`s, for ranges use [`timedelta_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.timedelta_range.html):

```
df['ActualTime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['ActualTime'].astype(str) + ':00')
b  = pd.timedelta_range('0', '24:00:00', freq='30T')

lab = [ str(i)[-8:-3] + ' - '+str(j)[-8:-3] for i,j in zip(b[:-1], b[1:]) ]
df['a'] = pd.cut(df['ActualTime'], bins=b, labels=lab)
print (df)
  ActualTime              a
0   12:30:00  12:00 - 12:30
1   12:31:00  12:30 - 13:00
2   12:46:00  12:30 - 13:00
3   13:05:00  13:00 - 13:30
4   13:22:00  13:00 - 13:30
5   13:48:00  13:30 - 14:00
6   14:05:00  14:00 - 14:30
```